# Error parsing JSON Dictionary with Swift decodable

Tags: json, swift, parsing, dictionary, decodable

I receive the following error:

> Error serialising json typeMismatch(Swift.Dictionary, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Dictionary but found an array instead.", underlyingError: nil))

Code:

```
//---------------
struct Currency: Decodable   {
    let symbol: String
    let price: String
}
var myDict: [Currency] = []
//---------------

func testParse(){
    let jsonUrlString = "https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/price"
    guard let url = URL(string: jsonUrlString) else
    { return }

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data,response,err) in
        guard let data = data else
        {
            print("Error: No data to decode")
            return
        }
        do
        {
            let exchanges = try
                JSONDecoder().decode(Currency.self, from: data)
            let X: [Currency] = [exchanges]
            self.myDict = X
            self.testFunc()
            print("binance: "+self.myDict[0].symbol + ": "+self.myDict[0].price)
        }
        catch let jsonErr
        {
            print("Error serialising json",jsonErr)
        }
    }
    .resume()
}
```

Is the issue with my struct layout? Or would it be how I'm parsing? I'd like to get a better understanding here for future reference. Therefore, if anyone could link a good Swift 4 guide it would be greatly appreciated. Alternatively, if you could give me a detailed answer that would be great (rather than spoon feeding the answer where I don't learn).

Answer (score 1):

Please **read** the error message carefully and learn to understand it. It's very clear.

> Expected to decode Dictionary but found an array instead

In other words: You want to decode a dictionary (`Currency`) but in truth it's an array (`[Currency]`).
In terms of `Decodable` a *dictionary* is the target struct or class.

And please don't name an object as `...dict` which is actually an array.

```
var myArray = [Currency]()

...

let exchanges = try JSONDecoder().decode([Currency].self, from: data)
self.myArray = exchanges
```